# Drupal: How do I modify my menu items' classnames?

Tags: php, drupal

I need unique ids or classnames per each item to style them individually - I'm using Drupal 6.1x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/310356

http://drupal.org/node/345624
and other in left side tree...

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Menu Class](http://drupal.org/project/menuclass) module to do that ;)